# Rendering Flash in the server

Tags: flash, rendering

I am trying to find a way to render a Flash object, more specifically a [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart), in the server, and save a screenshot of it to a temp file to embed it in on a PDF report.

I've found some solutions that use Javascript to generate a temp file in the browser, and then send it to the server (like [here](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/adv-upload-image.php)). However I need to generate reports automatically and send them as e-mail attachments, so I cannot render it using a browser.

Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP, you could generate swf files serverside using the Ming library: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php

In the newest PDF one can easily embed a PDF, so I dont know if you need to make a screenshot in order to show the flash in the PDF file. I dont know if this can be done programmatically, I just used Acrobat Pro.

Anyway, if you plan to embed a static screenshot/image in the PDF, why not generate a static image in the first place, using jpgraph http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/ or the graph component from eZ components http://www.ezcomponents.org/docs/tutorials/Graph (just suggestions for PHP, there are many others for Java or C#) ?

Comment: +1 for something like jpgraph. Screenshotting a Flash file seems like massively overcomplicating this.